# How to reload Json service every 10 seconds SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I am new in SAPUI5. I want to reload json service every 10 seconds.My controller code is.

```
modelServices :function()
    {

            var oModeldata = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("https://my-example.com/status/");
            this.getView().setModel(oModeldata, "datalake");
    },`
```

i call this method from init function of controller and my view is

```
    <TileContainer id="lstDataLakeView" tiles="{datalake>/collectionStatus}">
        <CustomTile class="sapMTile" borderVisible="true">
            <l:VerticalLayout class="sapUiContentPadding" width="100%">
                <l:content>
                    <core:Icon src="sap-icon://database" class="size2" color="#55acee">
                        <core:layoutData>
                            <FlexItemData growFactor="1"/>
                        </core:layoutData>
                    </core:Icon>
                    <FlexBox alignItems="End" justifyContent="End">
                        <items>
                            <Text text="Size {datalake>size}" tooltip="Size"/>
                        </items>
                    </FlexBox>
                </l:content>
            </l:VerticalLayout>
        </CustomTile>
    </TileContainer>
```

I want to refresh this tile after every 10 seconds. I know there is a method in javascript setTimeInterval(function,time); or setTimeOut() but I'm now sure here how can i use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
modelServices: function(){
    var oModeldata = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("https://my-example.com/status/");
    this.getView().setModel(oModeldata, "datalake");
    setInterval( function() {
        this.modelServices();
    }.bind(this), 10000 );    
},
```

Answer (score 3):

Please be careful not to call `setInterval()` in it's callback. Otherwise you will have 2 timers running after the first callback and double that every 10 seconds.

Also you should ensure that you stop the timer if your view is no longer displayed.

```js
modelServices :function()
{

        var oModeldata = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        this.getView().setModel(oModeldata, "datalake");
        this.intervalHandle = setInterval(function() { 
            //No need to create and assign a new model each time. Just load the data. 
            oModeldata. loadData("https://my-example.com/status/"); 
         },  10000); //Call setInterval only once
},
onExit:function() {
   // You should stop the interval on exit. 
   // You should also stop the interval if you navigate out of your view and start it again when you navigate back. 
   if (this.intervalHandle) 
      clearInterval(this.intervalHandle) ;
}
```

Comment: how i will manage if I've more then one datamodel.for exame https://my-example1.com/status/ and https://my-example2.com/status/

Comment: Each `setInterval` returns a handle that has to be passed to the `clearInterval` to end the timer. So if you want to use more than one interval, you could add `this.intervalHandle2` and so on or use an array to store the handles. **But** why not use the same interval to refresh all models? You can call as many `oModeldataX.loadData()` as you want inside of the interval callback because `loadData()` is asynchronous.  The data will be loaded in the background.